# found String, Required (String,String,String,Int): tuples-scala

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, tuples

I am having 3 ListBuffers of equal lengths.

> devicenamelist:ListBuffer[String]
>
> datelist:ListBuffer[String]
>
> wordcountssortedlistbuf[(String,Int)]

Now I need to convert them of the format

> ListBuffer(String,String,String,Int)

I tried to do the following

```
 var sortedrecords=scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(String,String,String,Int)]()

 for(i <- 0 to devicenamelist.length)
{

sortedrecords+=(devicenamelist(i),datelist(i),wordcountssortedlistbuf(i)._1,wordcountssortedlistbuf(i)._2)  

}
```

It gives me error as follows

> [error] found String
>
> Required (String,String,String,Int)

How is the list appending operation at the top giving only a single string when my intention was to create (String,String,String,Int). Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a set of parentheses in your `+=` line, but, please, don't do that, it hurts my eyes to see someone write something like this in scala.

Try something like this instead:

```
val sortedrecords = devicenamelist.zip(datelist).zip(wordcountssortedlistbuf)
 .map { case ((devicename, date), (word, count)) => 
   (devicename, date, word, count)
 }
```

Comment: @KevinMeredith it's not the tuple operators that hurt my eyes in the OP's code so much as a mutable buffer being filled in by an imperative loop. But, tuple operators, overly specific typing, and indexed access to lists don't help too ...